# Inserting dynamic pivot result into an existing table without knowing table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, exec, truncate, insert-into

I have a dynamic pivot table that produces an unknown number of columns until runtime. I am trying to clear the data out of an existing table and insert the results of my query into it. The problem that I am having is that I do not know what the table definition will be ahead of time because it is dynamic.

Here is the error I am getting: 
`Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

The pivoted column is a date column which could have 1 date or 1000+ dates.
How can I create a table definition that will match the data that I am trying to insert?

Here is my query:

```
 DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(rce.EcoDate) 
                             from PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542 AS rce
                             group by rce.EcoDate
                             order by rce.EcoDate
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                     ,1,1,'')

SELECT @colsUnpivot = stuff((SELECT ','+quotename(C.name)
FROM sys.columns AS C
WHERE C.object_id = object_id('PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542') AND
C.name in ('NDCash', 'DCash')--LIKE '%Cash' or C.Name like  'NetGas'
FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
 = 'select *
 --into ##hello
 from
 (
     SELECT  
        ReportRunCaseId,
        col, 
        EcoDate,  
        val
    FROM PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542  
unpivot
(
val
for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
) u
 ) x1
 pivot
 (
     max(val)
     for EcoDate in ('+ @colspivot +')
 ) p'

truncate table dbo.Table1
insert into dbo.Table1
exec(@query)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would `DROP` original table and just create new one on the fly using `SELECT INTO` clause.

by using `SELECT INTO` you do not need to create table before hand or worry what type and how many columns it will have. SQL Server will just create it for you.

Note: this only works when table does not exists.

Full documentation on `INTO` Clause http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

as another alternative you can always `SELECT INTO #temp` table that you can drop or use it to model your other table but I think this is extra work that you do not want to do.

Comment: Thank you. By using the `DROP` I was able to clear out the old data and insert the new data into a table with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 DROP TABLE dbo.Table1

 DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(rce.EcoDate) 
                             from PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542 AS rce
                             group by rce.EcoDate
                             order by rce.EcoDate
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                     ,1,1,'')

SELECT @colsUnpivot = stuff((SELECT ','+quotename(C.name)
FROM sys.columns AS C
WHERE C.object_id = object_id('PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542') AND
C.name in ('NDCash', 'DCash')--LIKE '%Cash' or C.Name like  'NetGas'
FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
 = 'select *
 into dbo.Table1
 from
 (
     SELECT  
        ReportRunCaseId,
        col, 
        EcoDate,  
        val
    FROM PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_542  
unpivot
(
val
for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
) u
 ) x1
 pivot
 (
     max(val)
     for EcoDate in ('+ @colspivot +')
 ) p'

exec(@query)
```